# Call a method in DAO class

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I am doing a project where I want to use `saveEmployee()` method from `EmployeeDAO` class in `EmployeeManager` class using a bean.

**Employee.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint.test;

public class Employee {

    EmployeeManager employeeManager;

    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private int dob;
    private String add;
    private int id;

    public void setfname(String fname){
        this.fname=fname;
    }
    public String getfname(){
        return fname;
    }
    public void setlname(String lname){
        this.lname=lname;
    }
    public String getlname(){
        return lname;
    }
    public void setdob(int dob){
        this.dob=dob;
    }
    public int getdob(){
        return dob;
    }
    public void setadd(String add){
        this.add=add;
    }
    public String getadd(){
        return add;
    }
    public void setid(int id){
        this.id=id;
    }
    public int getid(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setEmployeeManager(EmployeeManager employeeManager) {
        this.employeeManager = employeeManager;
    }
}
```

**EmployeeDAO.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint.test;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class EmployeeDAO implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {  
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;  
    }  

    public int saveEmployee(Employee e){  

        String fname = e.getfname();
        String lname = e.getlname();
        int dob=e.getdob();
        String add=e.getadd();
        int id = e.getid();
        Object p[] = {fname, lname,dob,add,id};
        String query="insert into employee values(?,?,?)";
        return jdbcTemplate.update(query, p);
    }

    public int deleteEmployee(int id){
        String sql ="delete from employee where id = ?";
        return jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[]{new Integer(id)}); 
    }

    public List<Employee> getAllEmployee(){
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        System.out.println("Connection starting.");
        Connection con = getConnection();
        String stm = "Select * from employee";
        List<Employee> records = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        try {   
            pst = con.prepareStatement(stm);
            pst.execute();
            rs = pst.getResultSet();

            while(rs.next()){
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.setfname(rs.getString(1));
                employee.setlname(rs.getString(2));
                employee.setdob(rs.getInt(3));
                employee.setadd(rs.getString(4));
                employee.setid(rs.getInt(5));
                records.add(employee);              
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return records;
    } 

    public Connection getConnection(){
        Connection con = null;

        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb";
        String user = "postgres";
        String password = "postgres";

        try {
            try {
                 Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println("Connection completed.");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
             System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
          finally{
        }
        return con;
    }


}
```

**EmployeeManager.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint.test;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import com.tutorialspoint.test.EmployeeDAO;
import com.tutorialspoint.test.Employee;

import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

public class EmployeeManager {
    //EmployeeDAO employeeDao=new EmployeeDAO();
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

    **EmployeeDAO employeeDao= (EmployeeDAO) ctx.getBean("edao");
        public void save(){
        employeeDao.saveEmployee();
    }**


    List<Employee>list=employeeDao.getAllEmployee();

}
```

My code is above. I want to call `saveEmployee()` method in `EmployeeDAO` class from `EmployeeManager`. How can I do that?

Comment: What is your actual question? Be more specific. Please also include code into your question, no screenshots.

Comment: @bsoulier I have added the code.I just want to access saveEmployee() method in EmployeeManager.java,where saveEmployee() method passed attr.of Employee.java.Whats the syntax...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EmployeeManager {

    public void save(){
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        EmployeeDAO employeeDao = (EmployeeDAO) ctx.getBean("edao");
        List<Employee>list = employeeDao.getAllEmployee();
        employeeDao.saveEmployee();
    }
}
```